# scss custom mixin overwrites change value does not replace, but adds it

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I want to overwrite the border-radius value **0** to **4px**.

**Does not replace, but adds it. What am I doing wrong?**

@import: theme.scss:

```
.uk-button {
    border-radius: 0;
    @if(mixin-exists(hook-button)) { @include hook-button(); }
}
```

custom.scss:

```
// Custom mixin overwrites
// that's correct?
@mixin hook-button() {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Unexpected result:**

```css
.uk-button {
    border-radius: 0; 
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Expected result:**

```css
.uk-button {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@include`, as it says, only adds/includes the particular rule(s), but does not replace them.

Theme SCSS should look like this:

```
.uk-button {
    @if(mixin-exists(hook-button)) { @include hook-button(); }
    @else { border-radius: 0; }
}
```